Geometric interpretation/intuition of the standard proof of Poincaré Lemma?
By "standard" I meant the proof using homotopy formula, i.e. pullback a form by $h(x,t)=xt$ then do fiber integration.
Is there a geometrical intuition of this proof, at least for low dimensions, e.g. 2-form in 3D? Historically, did this proof evolve into its present form from some basic proof for low dimensions?

For the case of $1$-forms, it really is intuitive and almost forced upon you: see this answer of mine. For the existence of a vector potential, see the same link (or in the language of forms, here). I think it is one of those things which seem very plausible by trial and error. The fully general case then just follows by careful adaptation of the argument. In fact I was given the 2-form case on an assignment and with some struggling, I managed to get the answer, so it doesn’t seem too bad.

oops for the 1-form case I meant to link to this, where I explained the motivation via the FTC and chain rule.

@peek-a-boo thanks for this. For 1-form indeed it is not difficult to understand. However, for 2-forms $\omega = a_{\mu_1\mu_2}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge dx^{\mu_2}$, we get an integration with an extra $t$ inside, $\int_0^1 t a_{\mu_1\mu_2}(tx) dt$. How do we appreciate this?

@peek-a-boo wait, the pullback gives us $h^*(f_Idx^I)=f_I t^k dx^I + t^{k-1}x^\mu f_{I}dtdx^{I-\mu}$ ($I-\mu$ just means $\mu$ is left out). $dx^I$ term drops out in the fiber integration (only $dtdx^{I-\mu}$ term remains). Nevermind this; what I wanted to ask is what's the geometrical meaning of $\int_0^1t^{k-1}f_I dt$?

tldr is I don’t really have a good geometric explanation, but as for  how the proof might have progressed, I think it’s just a matter of applying the FTC to a suitably chosen time-dependent family of differential forms (analogous to the $k=1$ case), and then grinding out the algebra (or more succinctly, using Cartan’s magic formula). But hopefully overall there’s an $\epsilon$ worth of insight in the answer :)

Very generally speaking, let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a vector bundle, $I$ an open interval and $\sigma$ a smooth 1-parameter family of sections, i.e a smooth map $\sigma:I\times M\to E$ such that each $\sigma(t,\cdot)$ is a section of $E$. Then, we can consider the various $t$-derivatives $\frac{\partial^k\sigma}{\partial t^k}:I\times M\to E$, and these are again a smooth 1-paramater family of sections. We also have the FTC: for any $a,b\in I$,
\begin{align}
\sigma(b,\cdot)-\sigma(a,\cdot)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial t}\,dt.\tag{$1$}
\end{align}
We interpret this pointwise in $M$ of course: for each $x\in M$, apply the FTC to the smooth curve $t\mapsto \sigma_t(x)$ in the fixed fiber $E_x$:
\begin{align}
\sigma(b,x)-\sigma(a,x)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial t}(t,x)\,dt,
\end{align}
So, equation $(1)$ is an equality of sections of $E$.

Now, take $E=\bigwedge^k(T^*M)$ for some integer $1\leq k\leq \dim M$, and fix a smooth $k$-form $\zeta$ on the product space $I\times M$. Then, letting $j_t:M\to I\times M$, $x\mapsto (t,x)$ be the time-$t$ injection, we can define a 1-parameter family of $k$-forms on $M$ by setting $\zeta_t=j_t^*\zeta$ ($\zeta_t$ plays the role of $\sigma(t,\cdot)$ above). Now, applying the FTC tells us
\begin{align}
\zeta_b-\zeta_a&=\int_a^b\frac{d}{dt}\left(j_t^*\zeta\right)\,dt,
\end{align}
as an equality of $k$-forms on $M$. Now, a simple enough calculation shows that $\frac{d}{dt}(j_t^*\zeta)=j_t^*(\mathscr{L}_T\zeta)$, where $T$ is the vector field on $I\times M$ which is the lift of the usual vector field $\frac{d}{dt}$ on $I$. So, by now applying Cartan’s magic formula, $\mathscr{L}_T=d\iota_T+\iota_Td$, and undoing the ‘spatial’ differentiation under the integral sign, we get
\begin{align}
\zeta_b-\zeta_a&=\int_a^bj_t^*(d\iota_T\zeta+\iota_Td\zeta)\,dt\\
&=d\int_a^bj_t^*(\iota_T\zeta)\,dt+\int_a^bj_t^*(\iota_T\,d \zeta).\tag{$2$}
\end{align}
Notice that equation $(2)$ is simply the FTC plus the Cartan’s magic formula. Whatever geometric intuition you have for the FTC, you can just apply that here, and the magic formula is well… chain rule plus some magical packaging into a condensed formula, so I don’t really have good geometric intuition here.
Next, suppose we have a $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$, and let $h:I\times M\to M$ be any smooth map. By applying $(2)$ to the $k$-form $\zeta=h^*\omega$, we get (setting $h_t=h\circ j_t$)
\begin{align}
h_b^*\omega-h_a^*\omega&=d\int_a^bj_t^*(\iota_Th^*\omega)\,dt+\int_a^bj_t^*(\iota_T dh^*\omega),
\end{align}
and so if in particular $\omega$ is closed, then so is $\zeta=h^*\omega$, and so
\begin{align}
h_b^*\omega-h_a^*\omega&=d\int_a^bj_t^*(\iota_Th^*\omega)\,dt.
\end{align}
Finally, for a smoothly contractible manifold we can find $h$ such that $h_0$ is constant, and $h_1$ is the identity, so we get
\begin{align}
\omega=d\int_0^1j_t^*(\iota_Th^*\omega)\,dt.\tag{$3$}
\end{align}
Equation $(3)$ proves Poincare’s lemma, and I just want to emphasize again that $d$ of the integrand in (3) is simply the time derivative $\frac{d}{dt}(j_t^*h^*\omega)=\frac{d}{dt}(h_t^*\omega)$. In the special case of a star-shaped open set $M\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ relative to the origin, by taking $h(t,x)=tx$, the integral term in (3) becomes, after some straightforward computation, $\sum\limits_{I}\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}^k(-1)^{\alpha-1}\left(\int_0^1\omega_I(tx)t^{k-1}x^{i_{\alpha}}\,dt\right)\,dx^{I-\alpha}$. So, really while each individual summand doesn’t seem to have any (geometric) meaning, this specific sum is simply (in the case of $d\omega=0$) this stuff is just what you’d get by first differentiating in $t$ then grinding out the resulting simplification.
I know this isn’t the best intuition for this type of proof, but I think it atleast follows the nice idea of first ‘getting an integral representation formula’ (namely equation (2)), and then simplifying as necessary (and it also naturally leads us to consideration of contractible manifolds).

One final approach which I just remembered is in Arnold’s book on classical mechanics. Given any chain $c$, consider the cone $P(c)$ over it relative to the origin. Then, you prove that there is a dual operation $P’$ taking forms to forms of one degree less such that for all $k$-forms $\omega$ and $(k-1)$-cycles $c$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_cP’(\omega)&=\int_{P(c)}\omega.
\end{align}
Coupling this with Stokes’ theorem and the formula $\partial\circ P+P\circ \partial =1$, yields the formula $dP’+P’d=1$, and so for closed forms $\omega$, we get $\omega=dP’\omega$, proving exactness.
This is essentially a dualized version of the proof via the fiber integration, but I guess Arnold deems this presentation more geometric because one can visualize cones?

I like your middle section very much (that contains (2)). This is beautiful. This finally starts to make sense! Was this your understanding or is there a reference to this? On the other hand I never really understood Arnold's system very well, starting from the line-intersection view of forms...

@Alex this is pretty much the proof in Wikipedia. But I think I’ve unknowingly reproduced what’s in Dieudonne’s Vol 9.

Dieudonne's which one again? Historical book?

No. Treatise on analysis. The last volume is only available in French (which I can’t read lol)

Thanks. is there a typo in $I\times X$, you meant $I\times M$?

yup, just fixed it.

By "lift of vector field $d/dt$" did you mean a pushforward?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
